# Проблема с отрисовкой нескольких слоев. Pygame. PyTMX

Tags: python, pygame

По итогу этого кода, у меня рисуется только 4ый слой, или любой, который будет отрисован последним. В TMX файле у меня 4 слоя, каждый с 1 непрозрачности, если это играет какую-то роль. Как можно отрисовать поле таким же, как и в Tiled?
1 Скрин из проги Tiled
2 То, что рисуется в PyGame
[image: Как отображается в Tiled]
[image: Как отображается в PyGam]

```
import pygame
import pytmx

pygame.init()
FPS = 60
class level:
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.map = pytmx.load_pygame(f'{filename}''.tmx')
        self.height = self.map.height
        self.width = self.map.width
        self.tile_width = self.map.tilewidth
        self.tile_height = self.map.tileheight

    def render(self, screen):
        for i in range(4):
            for y in range(self.height):
                for x in range(self.width):
                    image = self.map.get_tile_image(x, y, i)
                    if image is not None:
                        screen.blit(image,(x*self.tile_width,y*self.tile_height))

size = width, height = 960, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
level = level('data/new')
running = True
while running:
    level.render(screen)
    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.flip()
```